# How to count rows in database with the same value?

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble counting in my query report. I have a `table client` and `loanaccount` where client has rows of `LASTNAME` and `ENCODEDKEY(PK)` which is connected to the `loanaccount` table through the row called `ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY`. I've been wanting to count how many `ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY` is there in the `loanaccount` table with the same value as the `ENCODEDKEY(PK)`

My query code:

```
SELECT client.LASTNAME
    client.ENCODEDKEY,
    loanaccount.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY,
    COUNT(loanaccount.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY) AS LOANCOUNT
FROM client
    INNER JOIN loanaccount ON
    client.ENCODEDKEY = loanaccount.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY
ORDER BY LASTNAME ASC
```

My query output: *([Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTpgL.jpg) in case of typo.)*

```
LASTNAME         ENCODEDKEY                          LOANCOUNT
Yulo             8a8e8be6109ff9501610c46a6a601c7     1364
```

It counts all the `ACCOUNTHOLDERSKEY`s, which should be 1. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raw query appears incorrect to me.  You should be aggregating by the `ENCODEDKEY` from the `client` table, and then taking the count of that key:

```
SELECT
    c.ENCODEDKEY,
    c.LASTNAME,
    COUNT(la.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY) AS cnt
FROM client c
LEFT JOIN loanaccount la
    ON c.ENCODEDKEY = la.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY
GROUP BY
    c.ENCODEDKEY
ORDER BY
    c.LASTNAME
```

Note that I take a left join of `client` to `loanaccount`, and then count the `ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY` field from the latter table.  This will give us a count of zero should a certain `ENCODEDKEY` from `client` not match to anything in the `loanaccount` table.